# Knockout nested model properties

Tags: json, knockout.js

I need a feature like a repeating table in my web form and need to store my data in a JSON format like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1, "name": "T01", "title": "T01 form title", "totalPoints": "total of all points for sections below",
    "sections":
        [
            { "section": "First section", "point": 4 },
            { "section": "Second section", "point": 5 }
        ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2, "name": "T02", "title": "T02 form title", "totalPoints": "total of all points for sections below",
    "sections":
        [
            { "section": "First section", "point": 4 },
            { "section": "Second section", "point": 5 }
        ]
  }
```

]

I'm using knockout and I implemented top level of the structure below, but struggling with a nested sections.

Here is my attempts to structure my Model, please advise what option to use, or if this incorrect, please advise the right option:

```
function Form(data)
    {
        this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
        this.Total = ko.observable(data.Total);

    // Option 1, like an array
    this.Sections = ko.observableArray([
        {
             Section: data.Section,
             Point: data.Total
        }
    ]);

    // Option 2, like a function
    function Sections(data) {
        this.Section = ko.observable(data.Section),
        this.Point = ko.observable(data.Point)
    }
}
```

Later I push this data as a model to observable array like this, again I can push the top level, but couldn't nested properties:

```
    self.addForm = function () {
        self.forms.push(
            new Form({
                    Id: this.id(),
                    Name: this.name(),
                    Title: this.title(),
                    Total: function() // TODO
                    // Sections nested properties implementation
                })
            );
        self.name("");
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it's best to define two viewmodels:

1. `Form`, and
2. `Section`

Your `Form` will have three kinds of properties:

1. Regular `ko.observable` values, for `Id`, `Name` and `Title`

   Note: If some of those are static, it's best to not make them observable. I can imagine the `Id` will never change: you can signal this to other readers of your code by making it a regular string.
2. An `observableArray` for your list of `Section`s
3. A `pureComputed` for `Total` that sums up all your `Section` points

```js
function Section(points, title) {
  // TODO: check if you need these to be observable
  this.points = points;
  this.title = title;
};

// Create a new Section from a plain object
Section.fromData = function(data) {
  return new Section(data.point, data.section);
};

function Form(id, name, title, sections) {
  this.id = ko.observable(id);
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.title = ko.observable(title);

  // Map using our static constructor helper
  this.sections = ko.observableArray(
    sections.map(Section.fromData)
  );

  this.total = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.sections().reduce(function(sum, section) {
      return sum + section.points;
    }, 0);
  }, this);
}

// A helper to get from your data object to a new VM
Form.fromData = function(data) {
  return new Form(data.id, data.name, data.title, data.sections);
}

// Apply bindings
ko.applyBindings({
  forms: getTestData().map(Form.fromData)
});


// Your test data
function getTestData() {
  return [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "T01",
      "title": "T01 form title",
      "totalPoints": "total of all points for sections below",
      "sections": [{
          "section": "First section",
          "point": 4
        },
        {
          "section": "Second section",
          "point": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "T02",
      "title": "T02 form title",
      "totalPoints": "total of all points for sections below",
      "sections": [{
          "section": "First section",
          "point": 4
        },
        {
          "section": "Second section",
          "point": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: forms">
  <li>
    <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: sections">
      <li>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span> (
        <span data-bind="text: points"></span>)
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span data-bind="text: 'total: (' + total()"></span>)
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `Section` class is a bit plain; if you don't have additional requirements you could choose to use plain objects instead.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. Could you please advise what if I need Section points to be managed in UI?

Comment: You make it a `ko.observable`. In the `total` computed, you use `section.points()` to get the value. In your UI, you can bind to the points using `data-bind="value: points"`